# How to retrieve workflows in powershell?

Tags: 2013, powershell, designer-workflow

I'm trying to write a script to check the status of workflows in a list. I have tried a couple different ways but I never get anything to return.

```
foreach($item in $list.Items){
    $item.Workflows   
}

$list.WorkFlowAssociations

$web.WorkFlowAssociations

$site.WorkflowManager.GetItemWorkflows($item)
```

Each of these statements return nothing. The list and site I am checking have active workflows created in designer that I can see and run in SharePoint just fine, but cannot seem to find them with powershell.

Comment: Do you use 2010 or 2013 workflow engine?

Comment: They are 2013 workflows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the SharePoint 2010 workflows (or 2010 workflows in a 2013 environment) you can run this.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$wf = @()

$web = get-spweb -Identity https://spwebUrl
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]

foreach ($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
    $wfAssociations += $($wf)
}

if ($wfAssociations.count -ge 1)
{
    foreach ($item in $list.Items)
    {
        foreach($workflow in $item.workflows)
        {
            $wfName = $wf.Name
            $wfStatus = $workflow.InternalState
            $wfListItem = $workflow.ItemName

            write-host "Workflow Title: $wfName Status: $wfStatus ListItem: $wfListItem"
        }
    }
}
```

For a 2013 workflow, you have to do it little difference because you have to access the workflows from the workflow manager.

I did some tests but i can't manage to pick up the title, only the GUID.

You might be able to figure it out, or the ID is maybe enough for you. I need to get back to work. :)

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$web = get-spweb -Identity https://spwebUrl
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]

$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
$wf = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($list.ID)
$wfis=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    $workflowInstances=$wfis.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($list.ID,$item.ID)

    foreach($wf in $workflowInstances) 
    {
        #$wfName = $wf.Name **<---- Won't work here.**
        $wfID= $wf.ID
        $wfStatus = $wf.Status
        $wfListItem = $item.Name

        write-host "Workflow Title: $wfID Status: $wfStatus ListItem: $wfListItem"
    }

}
```

**Update**

Corrected the double use of the variable $wf and added MickB suggestions to get the name property.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$web = get-spweb -Identity https://spwebUrl
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]

$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
$sub = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
$wfs = $sub.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($list.ID)
$wfis=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    $workflowInstances=$wfis.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($list.ID,$item.ID)

    foreach($wf in $workflowInstances) 
    {
        $wfName = $wfs | ?{$_.Id -eq $wf.WorkflowSubscriptionId} | select -ExpandProperty Name
        $wfID= $wf.ID
        $wfStatus = $wf.Status
        $wfListItem = $item.Name

        write-host "Workflow Title: $wfName Status: $wfStatus ListItem: $wfListItem"
    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. Also, for the name I changed the initial `$wf` variable to `$wfs` to differentiate it from the `foreach` loop variable. I got the name but using `$wfName = $wfs | ?{$_.Id -eq $wf.WorkflowSubscriptionId} | select -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: Super! Thanks for finding that and with adding a way to get the name out! :)

Comment: Is it possible to get the last run time of Workflow instance.

Comment: @Pavan 2010 or 2013?