# How do I write a PowerShell script to display the count of each version of the workflow used in the SharePointlist by each item

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, workflow, powershell

In the SharePoint list, each item has a workflow of a particular version. How do I display all the workflows and their individual count from that SharePoint list using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

the below script could be a starting point. in that script you provide the workflow name, then it will check which list item is associate and running.

```
$workflowNameToCheck = "My Sample Workflow"
$url = "http://SharePointDemo"
$spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$workflowBase = $spweb.WorkflowTemplates | where {$_.Name -eq $workflowNameToCheck}
$spWeb.Dispose()
foreach($spWeb in $spSite.AllWebs)
{
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $spWeb.Lists.Count; $i++)
    {
        $spList = $spweb.Lists[$i]
        $assoc = $spList.WorkflowAssociations | where {$_.BaseId -eq $workflowBase.Id.ToString() `
                            -and $_.RunningInstances -gt 0}
    if($assoc -ne $null)
        {
        foreach($item in $spList.Items)
            {
                if(($item.Workflows | where {$_.InternalState -eq "Running"}) -ne $null)
                {
                    write-output "$($spWeb.Name) | $($spList.Title) | $($item.Name)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $spWeb.Dispose()
}
$spSite.Dispose()
```

you can read more here: [PowerShell Script To Find Instances Of Running SharePoint Workflow](https://briantjackett.com/2010/07/12/powershell-script-to-find-instances-of-running-sharepoint-workflow/)

Also check this: [How to retrieve workflows in powershell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163974/how-to-retrieve-workflows-in-powershell)

Comment: I do not want individual workflow of each item in the list. I wanted all the different workflows that are used by the items of the list and the count of each workflow used by items in the list.