# How to display workflow name and workflows in progress count from SharePoint 2013 using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am able to navigate till workflow associations. Can anyone help me to display the workflows in progress count and the workflow name[image]

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/164066/6382

Comment: You can check the similar post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/6974e907-db89-4f8f-a045-5d2e224441b2/get-running-workflows-sp2013?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Comment: No. I don't have to iterate through the items. I am able to get the workflow name by using workflowAssociation.Name. Same way is there a way to get the Workflows in progress??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the PowerShell as following:

```
$web=Get-SPWeb http://SpSiteName
$list=$web.Lists["ListName"]
$wf=$list.WorkflowAssociations | where {$_.RunningInstances -gt 0}
$wf | select Name,ParentList,RunningInstances | Format-List;
```