# Check which items running on previous version of SharePoint workflow instance?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow

I have a number of items from a list running on a previous version of workflow instance. Is there an easy way of checking which items are running on a particular version of workflow instance instead of individually checking each item in the list?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell cmdlets to get the related item information and export them into Excel or csv.

A demo:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$wf = @()

$web = get-spweb -Identity https://spwebUrl
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]

foreach ($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
    $wfAssociations[$wfAssociations,$wf]
}

if ($wfAssociations.count -ge 1)
{
    foreach ($item in $list.Items)
    {
        foreach($workflow in $item.workflows)
        {
            $wfName = $wf.Name
            $wfStatus = $workflow.InternalState
            $wfListItem = $workflow.ItemName

            write-host "Workflow Title: $wfName Status: $wfStatus ListItem: $wfListItem"
        }
    }
}
```

[How to retrieve workflows in powershell?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163974/how-to-retrieve-workflows-in-powershell)

Comment: I get an error stating - " The term 'get-SPweb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again". The name is not incorrect...